# Swift enum case declaration syntax

Tags: swift, enums

I'm new to Swift. The code below came from "the swift programming language 2.1". I have noticed that when declaring "case" for "enum Rank: Int", the book used

```
case Two = 2, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten
```

I assume it is equivalent to

```
case Two = 2,
case Three = 3,
....
case Ten = 10
```

Is my assumption correct? and if yes, what kind of syntax is this? Is there any other situation where it could be used?

```
struct BlackjackCard {
    enum Suit: Character {
        case Spades = "♠", Hearts = "♡", Diamonds = "♢", Clubs = "♣"
    }

    enum Rank: Int {
        case Two = 2, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten
        case Jack, Queen, King, Ace
        struct Values {
            let first: Int, second: Int?
        }
        var values: Values {
            switch self {
            case .Ace:
                return Values(first: 1, second: 11)
            case .Jack, .Queen, .King:
                return Values(first: 10, second: nil)
            default:
                return Values(first: self.rawValue, second: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    let rank: Rank, suit: Suit
    var description: String {
        var output = "suit is \(suit.rawValue),"
        output += " value is \(rank.values.first)"
        if let second = rank.values.second {
            output += " or \(second)"
        }
        return output
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the section on enumerations. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html   This value is called "raw value", and if it is not specified, it is one larger than the previous enum option's raw value.

Comment: @Thilo Thank you very much for helping out! Sorry to trouble you again, but could you please tell me what "self" is referring to in the context of this particular switch statement?

Comment: In the context of an enum, you can think of `self` as referring to an instance of the enum that maps to a particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called an "Implicitly Assigned Raw Value" and you can read about it in the [Swift Programming Language Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html):

Implicitly assigned values can either be `Int` or `String` types, depending on how the enum is declared.

If the enum is declared to be an `Int` type, any values not explicitly assigned become "one greater than the previous case".  If no values are explicitly assigned, the first enum case gets the value 0, followed by 1, 2, 3, etc.

```
enum Foo: Int {
    case Bar, Baz, Boz  // values are 0, 1, 2 respectively
}
```

To access the "raw value" explicitly, you use the enum member named `rawValue` which Swift provides:

`let anInt = Foo.Bar.rawValue  // anInt == 0`

If the enum is a `String` type, the value is implicitly assigned the name of the case, thus:

```
enum Foo: String {
    case Bar, Baz, Boz
}
```

Has raw values of "Bar", "Baz", and "Boz".

Note that you can override any of these values by explicitly setting them where the case is specified, e.g.:

```
enum Foo: String {
    case Bar = "Something"
    case Baz = "Something else"
    case Boz  // implicitly assigned "Boz"
}
```

and in either case, the rawValue is obtained like so:

`let aString = Foo.Bar.rawValue  // "Something"`

Comment: Thank you very much!! So great to have people like you helping out!!